# System.NullReferenceException in Python .NET using msl.loadlib and a DLL

Tags: python, .net, dll

I have an SDK from an USB measuring instrument with a sample program written in Visual Basic but I want to use Python to control the instrument.

I use the LoadLibrary from msl.loadlib to load the .net DLL in Python.

The instrument responds fine and does what I ask, however I get a `System.NullReferenceException` at the last line, which I don't understand. Does anyone has an idea? Could it be a bug from the .NET?

Code:

```
from msl.loadlib import LoadLibrary
from time import sleep
import ctypes


class sekonic():
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        
        NET = LoadLibrary(r'C:\Users\Adrien Lucca\Desktop\WORKSPACE\mechelen\C7000_SDK_old.dll', 'net')
        
        self.name = name 
        self.lib = NET.lib.C7000.SDK(ctypes.c_ulong)

#the machine and its functions
device = sekonic("sek")

#connect to the machine
SDKResult = device.lib.SK_Connect() 
  
while (device.lib.SKF_STATUS_COM.SUCCESS != SDKResult):
    print("connection failed")
    print('try turning the C7000 ON')
    SDKResult = device.lib.SK_Connect()
print("connection established")

#initialize variables
MeasResult = device.lib.SKS_MEAS_RESULT()
Config = device.lib.SKS_MEAS_CONFIG()
DeviceInfo = device.lib.SKS_DEVICE_INFO()

#get info
SDKResult = device.lib.SK_GetDeviceInfo(DeviceInfo)
if (SDKResult[1].Status == 0):
    print ("IDLE")
if (SDKResult[1].Remote == 0):
    print ("REMOTE OFF")


#set remote
SDKResult = device.lib.SK_SetRemoteMode(1) 
  
while (device.lib.SKF_STATUS_COM.SUCCESS != SDKResult):
    print("set remote mode failed ")
    SDKResult = device.lib.SK_SetRemoteMode(1) 


#get info
SDKResult = device.lib.SK_GetDeviceInfo(DeviceInfo)
if (SDKResult[1].Status == 0):
    print ("IDLE")
if (SDKResult[1].Remote == 1):
    print ("REMOTE ON")


#configuration 
Params = device.lib.SK_GetMeasConfig(Config)

if (Params[1].MeasuringMode) != 0:
    Params[1].MeasuringMode= 0
if (Params[1].MeasuringMode) == 0:
    print("Measuring Mode: AMBIENT")
if (Params[1].FieldOfView) != 1:
    Params[1].FieldOfView = 1 
if (Params[1].FieldOfView) == 1:
    print("10deg Observer")
if (Params[1].ExposureTime) != 0:
    Params[1].ExposureTime = 0
if (Params[1].ExposureTime) == 0:
    print("AUTO exposure")
if (Params[1].MeasuringMethod) !=0:
    Params[1].MeasuringMethod = 0
if (Params[1].MeasuringMethod) ==0:
    print("SINGLE measurement mode")

#write new parameters
device.lib.SK_SetMeasConfig(Params[1])



#
# Start measurement 
#
Measurement = device.lib.SK_StartMeasuring()

i = 0
SDKResult = device.lib.SK_GetDeviceInfo(DeviceInfo)
if (SDKResult[1].Status==3):
    print("MEASURING")

while SDKResult[1].Status == 3:

    sleep(.1)

    SDKResult = device.lib.SK_GetDeviceInfo(DeviceInfo)

    if(i>=10000):
        print("error waiting 100s")
        break 
    i += 1

if (SDKResult[1].Status == 0):
    print ("IDLE")
    
#get the measurement results
#HERE IT CRASHES
#System.NullReferenceException: La reference d'objet n'est pas definie a une instance d'un objet.
SDKResult = device.lib.SK_GetMeasuringResult(MeasResult)
```

Returns:

```
connection established
IDLE
IDLE
REMOTE ON
Measuring Mode: AMBIENT
10deg Observer
AUTO exposure
SINGLE measurement mode
MEASURING
IDLE

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adrien Lucca\Desktop\WORKSPACE\mechelen\SekoniC7000.py", line 125, in <module>
    SDKResult = device.lib.SK_GetMeasuringResult(MeasResult)
System.NullReferenceException: La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet.
   à C7000.SDK.SK_GetMeasuringResult(SKS_MEAS_RESULT& MeasResult)
```

Comment: Maybe you should attach a .NET debugger. It's unlikely a bug of .NET (Microsoft). It might be a bug in the .NET DLL but I consider that unlikely, too. The problem is too obvious, so that many people should have had that before.

Comment: Any idea how to add such a debugger into Eclipse/Pydev with Python3 32bit?

Comment: Visual Studio (Community Edition): Debug / Attach to process.

Comment: That's very nice of you but unfortunately I don't seem to understand at all how this works. I am completely new to Visual Studio, usually using simple notepad applications and run .py files from Eclipse

Comment: Can you share the .NET DLL? I could have a look into it using dotPeek or so.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vtwS9H-tA5iYZ0xPkU0hvtegH7d7etBF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x5QZ4vqPH6_ZEf-iURTOG3UzDxSiN8Qq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There are two DLLs, but one accesses the other, so it's only necessary to load the C7000_SDK

Comment: dotPeek decompiles them perfectly

Comment: Here's also a sample .vb program from the SDK if that helps https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uEPKY1RBdhoi4NTm6zML8HuAhVnHCa7d/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If drive doesn't work 
https://boards.wetransfer.com/board/sta6zr07ocgawq22e20210524211857/latest?token=d61443f5-a935-47c8-98a4-1ba7d353b63b